# Adding new attribute to existent document with mongoose

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose, crud

I'm trying to update an existing document to add a new attribute with js.

```
User.findOne({ name: req.body.user.name }).exec((err, user) => {
    // Handle database errors
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
        user['name'] = req.body.user.name;
        user['mail'] = req.body.user.mail;
        user['apikey'] = req.body.user.apiKey;
        console.log('ApiKey: ' + req.body.user.apiKey);
        console.log('User: ' + user   );
        user.save((err, saved) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log("error");
              res.status(500).send(err)
            }
            res.json({ user: saved });
        });
    }
});
```

But it seems that I can't add the new one base on the logs.
The new one It's not a required field. This is my model:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: 'String', required: true },
    mail: { type: 'String', required: true },
    password: { type: 'String', required: true },
    apiKey: { type: 'String', required: false }
});

let User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I'm just getting started with mongoDB using mongoose so I'm have many basic things wrong.

Comment: you mean, you are are not able to update the document?

Comment: I'm able to update all of the existing fields. But i can't add a new one(in this case 'apikey').

Comment: Your model has `apiKey` in camelCase and you are updating with `apikey` which makes difference... so try with this `user['apiKey']` or you can try with update query as well `User.findOneAndUpdate(
 { name: req.body.user.name },
 { $set: req.body.user }
)`

Comment: thats what the issue should be.

Comment: OMG! I'm so stupid. Thanks guys!